# How to accept JSON in SOAP WS, without XML

Tags: c#, json, xml, web-services, soap

I have written a WEBSERVICE with SOAP in .Net 3.5 version. When you display ASMX file on IE, it shows the information below.

I told my customer that I can accept JSON object that they send to me. I am acccepting a token(string) and param1(JSON object). But, token and param1 are still sent within XML. Customer told me that he wants to send me only json. How can I change it the way he wants? Can anybody tell me what to do?

```
POST /Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/PaymentRequest"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <PaymentRequest xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <guid>string</guid>
      <param1>
        <organisationId>string</organisationId>
        <kdv>decimal</kdv>
        <bsmv>decimal</bsmv>
        <payment>
          <paymentId>string</paymentId>
          <signedDate>dateTime</signedDate>
          <amount>decimal</amount>
          <installment>int</installment>
          <appliedRate>decimal</appliedRate>
          <cardId>string</cardId>
        </payment>
      </param1>
    </PaymentRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-) You add your service above  `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`

Like this

```
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
         JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         Context.Response.Clear();
         Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";           
         Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize("HelloWorld"));
    }
```

2-) Add your web.config this handler part

```
configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory"
                 verb="*" path="*.asmx"
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                 resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: But, I dont want to respond wiith JSON, I want to receive JSON parameter

Comment: Your customer send data  with this format  ContentType = "application/json" ?